# What is the minimum of n to construct a Markov chain?

Tags: probability, markov-process

Wiki gives this [definition of a discrete-time Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain)

> a sequence of random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$, ... with the Markov property, namely that the probability of moving to the next state depends only on the present state and not on the previous states:
>
> $\Pr(X_{n+1}=x\mid X_{1}=x_{1},X_{2}=x_{2},\ldots ,X_{n}=x_{n})=\Pr(X_{n+1}=x\mid X_{n}=x_{n}),$
>   if both conditional probabilities are well defined, that is, if
>
> $\Pr(X_{1}=x_{1},\ldots ,X_{n}=x_{n})>0.$
>
> The possible values of $X_i$ form a countable set S called the state space of the chain.

Wiki also uses this [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_Markov_chains) to illustrate Markov chains.

> The probabilities of weather conditions (modeled as either rainy or
>   sunny), given the weather on the preceding day, can be represented by
>   a transition matrix:
>
> ${\displaystyle P={\begin{bmatrix}0.9&0.1\\0.5&0.5\end{bmatrix}}}$
>
> The matrix P represents the weather model in which a sunny day is 90% likely to be followed by another sunny day, and a rainy day is 50% likely to be followed by another rainy day. The columns can be labelled "sunny" and "rainy", and the rows can be labelled in the same order.
>
> The weather on day 1 is known to be sunny. This is represented by a vector in which the "sunny" entry is 100%, and the "rainy" entry is 0%:
>
> ${\displaystyle \mathbf {x} ^{(0)}={\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}}}$

for day n + 1(**Note**: the original value on wiki is n, which seems to be incorrect)

> ${\mathbf  {x}}^{{(n)}}={\mathbf  {x}}^{{(0)}}P^{n}$

The superscript (n) is an index, and not an exponent.

In the particular case, the state space of the chain is {rainy , sunny}

so, what is the minimum of n?

in particular, ${\displaystyle \Pr(X_0=sunny) = 1,}$
is this a Markov chain?

${\displaystyle \Pr(X_{1}=sunny\mid X_0=sunny)}$,
is this a Markov chain?

${\displaystyle \Pr(X_{2}=sunny\mid X_0=sunny,X_{1}=sunny)}$
is this a Markov chain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Markov chain is a stochastic process.

A [stochastic process](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-MCI.pdf) in discrete time n ∈ $N$ = {0, 1, 2, . . .} is a sequence of random variables (rvs) $X_0, X_1, X_2$, . . . denoted by $X = \{X_n : n ≥ 0\}$.

So, for your question, each of them is a Markov chain.